# Nativescript android how to download remote image to device?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

can anyone please help me how to download remote image to mobile using nativescript android app?
For example,

```
<StackLayout>
   <Image [src]="remoteImgUrl"></Image>
   <Label tap="downloadImg({{remoteImgUrl}})" text="Download">
</StackLayout>
```

when user clicks on 'Download' I need to save that image in android device.

Comment: You could use for Android `nativescript-downloadmanager` -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-downloadmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example based on this app [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank):

TypeScript

```
export function saveFile(res: ImageSource) {

    fileName = "some-image-name" + ".jpeg";

    var folderPath;
    if (application.android) {
        var androidDownloadsPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        folderPath = fileSystem.path.join(androidDownloadsPath, "MyImages");
    } 

    var folder = fileSystem.Folder.fromPath(folderPath);
    var path = fileSystem.path.join(folderPath, fileName);
    var exists = fileSystem.File.exists(path);

    if (!exists) {
        var saved = res.saveToFile(path, enums.ImageFormat.jpeg);
    }

}
```

The method accepts imageSource as a parameter so you can call it with fromUrl method for imageSource e.g.

```
import * as imageSource from "image-source";
imageSource.fromUrl(IMAGE_URL_HERE)
     .then(res => {
          saveFile(res); // 
      })
```